# Execute script in edit mode when scripts finish compiling, without an object in the scene

Tags: unity, editors

I need to inspect some method information before game starts to implement something in Unity.

I can run the script by [ExecuteInEditMode] attribute, however it only works if at least one object in the scene has the script as component.

What I want is to run the script in edit mode as soon as Unity finishes each recompilation, without a scene object, so other developers can use my library/framework without creating objects manually.

How do I run the script in edit mode after the scripts recompile, without creating an object in the current scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using "[InitializeOnLoad](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RunningEditorCodeOnLaunch.html)" attribute. Using this attribute without MonoBehaviour, you can run the code what you want.

Comment: It looks like this executes the method when the Run button is pressed, rather than "right after script compilation" as you'd described. Is that still suitable for your needs, or do you need a method that fires earlier, without the user manually pressing the run button?

Comment: @DMGregory No, it always run right after script compilation over.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the "monobehaviour" attribute from your script. This will seperate the script from any visual objects.